# Is there a way to create a like button inside iOS app for Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, ios7, facebook-like

Is there a way to create a like button inside a native iOS app for Facebook page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this tutorial here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app

It shows you everything you need to do to set up Like box with your iOS app.

Comment: Thanks John, this will help!

Answer (score 0):

See the url:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/like-button

This is the easiest way to show the like button in ios app but it still beta feature.

Here is the code:

```
[FBSettings enableBetaFeature:FBBetaFeaturesLikeButton];
[FBSettings enablePlatformCompatibility:NO];
FBLikeControl *like = [[FBLikeControl alloc] init];
like.objectID = @"http://shareitexampleapp.parseapp.com/photo1/";
like.likeControlHorizontalAlignment=FBLikeControlHorizontalAlignmentRight;
like.likeControlStyle=FBLikeControlStyleBoxCount;
[self.view addSubview like];
```

Answer (score 0):

This is no longer possible since 2017... could be possible another way.

reference: https://marketingland.com/facebook-will-disable-like-button-third-party-mobile-apps-228159